# Replacing a string in all config files across machines with a script

Tags: script, batch, powershell

I have the below task and I am wondering what would be the best and quick way to do this. I am thinking scripting rather than a C# app but struggling with scripting in DOS. I wanted to use powershell but not sure if all the machines have powershell installed :

I have around 15 windows machines and in each machine, I want to find all *.config files (in say C:\ and D:) and replace a specific word (db name).

I can execute this locally or execute this remotely, since I have login access to the machines. But the tough part is the script.

Any pointers would be great to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be a script? Otherwise there are portable apps that can do this easily, or even command-line search/replace utils. See for example http://superuser.com/questions/593509, http://superuser.com/questions/87544, http://superuser.com/questions/199818, http://superuser.com/questions/394526, http://superuser.com/questions/564623 and many more.

Comment: yes, script was not really useful. Thanks for the utility idea, used grep win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a tool like grepWin for this.

[grepWin site](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html)

You should be able to give it the string to search for, then the string to replace with, along with the location to search. Should be easy as can be.

Comment: Thanks, yes, grepwin was helpful and I used the same.